# How to access Database to perform Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I tried to perform filtering based on Position and Department but I'M getting this error probaply for the way I'm accessing. I tried a different way but the error still the same. I'm access it in wrong way? I Don't know what's the problem

Appreciate your help!

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult' to 'dotnet_rpg.Models.ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<dotnet_rpg.Dtos.Employee.GetEmployeeDto>>'

Controller

```
        [HttpGet("search")]

    public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>> SearchEmployee(string text) 
        { 

              var response = await _employeeService.searchEmployee(text);
            if (response.Data == null)
            {
                return NotFound(response);
            }
            return Ok(response);
        }

        }
    }
```

Service Layer

```
           public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>> searchEmployee(string text)
            { 
        

                var response = new ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>();
            var dbEmployee = await _context.Employees
                .Include(a => a.FirstName)
                .Where(p => p.Position.ToLower().Contains(text) ||
                p.Department.ToLower().Contains(text))
                .ToListAsync();
           response.Data = dbEmployee.Select(c => _mapper.Map<GetEmployeeDto>(c)).ToList();
            return response;   

        }
```

DataContext

```
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }


   public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: your error message indicated the response you queried from the database not match the datatype you used to store the data. for example, what you expected to query from the database is a list, but the query result is null. You'd better to check the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer

search

```
           public async   Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>> searchEmployee(string text)
            { 
        

                var response = new ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>();
            var dbEmployee = await _context.Employees
                
                .Where(p => p.Position.ToLower().Contains(text) ||
                p.Department.ToLower().Contains(text))
                .ToListAsync();
           response.Data = dbEmployee.Select(c => _mapper.Map<GetEmployeeDto>(c)).ToList();
            return response;   

        }
```

controller

```
 

      [HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<List<GetEmployeeDto>>>> SearchEmployee(string text) 
{ 
    var response = await _employeeService.searchEmployee(text);
    if (response.Data == null)
    {
        return NotFound(response);
    }
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a build error?

The controller method is expecting a type of 'ServiceResponse<<List<GetEmployeeDto>>' where as the code returns 'NotFound' or 'Ok', both of which are IActions.

Change the controller return type and return statements to as @owwoj mentioned.